# How to name variables without plural in a for-each loop?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, variables, loops

How do you name loop variables when the list item is named after something without a plural? For instance (in python): `[x for x in sheep]`. `x` is not a great name, but sheep have/has no plural that distinguishes it from the singular.

Is there a general best-practice for naming such variables, to emphasise clarity, and avoid confusion?

Comment: To the downvoters and closevoters, I'm asking if there is a best practice: "best practice (noun):commercial or professional procedures that are accepted or prescribed as being correct or most effective." This is not something that should be opinion based.

Comment: my go-to variable name for items in a collection is: `item`!  Kind of obvious, no?  Alternatively, keep the singular variable name and rename the collection.  `[sheep for sheep in sheepCollection]`.

Comment: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/218240)

Comment: @Pureferret, unfortunately, best practices questions are also usually offtopic here.  And, as far as I know, there is no widely recognized best practice for this, so it does far squarely under "primarily opinion based".

Comment: I've been know to use "theSheep" or "thisSheep".  Or just "s" as suggested by Kilian Foth if the scope is small enough.

Comment: @DanPichelman thanks for that. I don't use this SE much, so your ways are foreign and strange to me.

Comment: Don't feel bad.  Our ways are foreign and strange to some long-timers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names should be expressive in direct proportion to their scope. A loop variable should have a really small scope, so it's perfectly alright to just call it `s`. If this makes the code unreadable, you should refactor the loop code into a method, not find a longer variable name.